# How could i design a layout like this?

Tags: android-listview, android-fragments, android-menu

I have to develop a ftp file tranfer application.

How could i design a layout like this.

[image: 2 two fragment]

Do I need 2 fragment and 2 menu?

Do you have any example project or source code?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **SherlockNavigationDrawer**

[Here](https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer)

or **Android's drawers**

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html